# JSON How can I make an object translate to Name.First instead of Name[First]?

Tags: ajax, json, object, field

I'm working on a website and I have a controller that takes in a lot of data, including a Name field:

```
public Name name { get; set; }
```

defined as follows:

```
public class Name
{
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ\s-'.*]*$")]
    public string First { get; set; }
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ\s-'.*]*$")]
    public string Last { get; set; }
    public string DatabaseName { get; set; }

}
```

I've been using an MVC page that passes data through this controller, and it works. All the fields on this page are MVC HTML helpers, so I have an input box:

```
@HTML.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name.First)
```

Using Fiddler, I'm able to see that the data is being passed as Name.First : "john", which is correct, and this returns the results correctly.

However, I have another page that I am not able to use HTML helpers on. For most of the fields, I'm able to get the data correctly using JSON and an asynchronous AJAX call:

```
var queryModel = {
    SoundEx: $("#Soundex").val(),
    ExactSearch: $(".exact").val(),
    Name : {First : $('.col-sm-5 > .form-control[placeholder="First and Middle Names"]').val(), 
    Last: $('.col-sm-5 > .form-control[placeholder="Last Name"]').val()},
    FromYear: $('.form-control[id="yearFrom"]').val(),
    ToYear: $('.form-control[id="yearTo"]').val(),
    SelectedType: $("#RecordDropdown").val(),
    Location: $('.form-control[placeholder="Enter Location"]').val(),
    Favorites: $("#Favorite").val(),
    Free: $("#Free").val(),
    Images: $("#Images").val(),
    Category: $("#category").val(),
    Database: $("#database").val(),
    Keywords: $('.form-control[placeholder="Enter terms or words"]').val(),
    FamilyMembers: [{ Relationship: $("#Type1").val(), Firstname: $("#First1").val(), LastName: $("#Last1").val() },
                    { Relationship: $("#Type2").val(), Firstname: $("#First2").val(), LastName: $("#Last2").val() },
                    { Relationship: $("#Type3").val(), Firstname: $("#First3").val(), LastName: $("#Last3").val() }],
    PageNum: 1,
    PageSize: 20,
    newSearch: 1,
    SortBy: "Relevance"

}

$(resultsDiv).html("<h3>Searching...</h3>");

resultsDiv.show();

$.ajax({
    url: "http://nehgs.mvc/SearchResults/Results",
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'text/html',
    success: function (info) {
        $(resultsDiv).html(info.responseText);
    },
    data: queryModel

});
```

All of my search fields work except for the name and relationship fields, i.e. whatever is typed in them is correctly searched for in my database, and the results returned are correct. However, when the name or relationship fields are filled out, they don't get searched for; I still get data returned, but those fields are treated as though they are blank.

In Fiddler, I can see that these fields are being passed as

```
Name[First]
```

and

```
Relationships[0][Firstname]
```

Whereas in the page where those fields are working, they are being passed as

```
Name.First
```

and

```
Relationships[0].Firstname
```

This is the only thing I can think of that would cause this issue. How can I make the JSON pass is as Name.First instead of Name[First]?

Comment: If you replace the jquery `.val` function for `Name` with a hardcoded string `{ First: "FirstName", Last: "LastName" }` do you successfully bind this value in your controller action? Do the same for `Relationships`. Also, what does your C# queryModel look like?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using the toDictionary() plugin available on this page:

http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2010/12/sending-complex-json-objects-to-aspnet.html